# Duplicate Form using button

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to duplicate 4 input text. For example I want to duplicate 'Produk Simpanan Saham', then only 4 input on 'Produk Simpanan Saham' `div` will be duplicated. I already tried a few methods using jQuery but it seem doesn't work.

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <br><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    Upload File :
    <input type="file" name="file">
  </div>
  <div class="saham">
    <div class="w3-container w3-black">
      <h3>
        <center>Produk Simpanan Saham</center>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <label for="kp_produk">Kode Produk :</label>
    <input type="text" name="kp_produk" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label for="produk_saham">Produk :</label>
    <input type="text" name="produk_saham" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label for="bunga_saham">Bunga :</label>
    <input type="text" name="bunga_saham" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label for="ket_saham">Keterangan :</label>
    <input type="text" name="ket_saham" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="harian">
    <div class="w3-container w3-black">
      <h3>
        <center>Produk Simpanan Harian</center>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <label for="kp_harian">Kode Produk :</label>
    <input type="text" name="kp_harian" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label for="produk_harian">Produk :</label>
    <input type="text" name="produk_harian" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label for="bunga_harian">Bunga :</label>
    <input type="text" name="bunga_harian" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label for="ket_harian">Keterangan :</label>
    <input type="text" name="ket_harian" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Comment: `clone()` sounds like what you need to use. It's impossible to say why your code isn't working without seeing it

Answer (score 0):

you mush have blueprint of field first like

```
var blueprint= '<div class="saham">'+
'<div class="w3-container w3-black">'+
  '<h3>'+
    '<center>Produk Simpanan Saham</center>'+
  '</h3>'+
'</div>'+
'<label for="kp_produk">Kode Produk :</label>'+
'<input type="text" name="kp_produk[]" class="form-control">'+
'<br>'+
......
```

used [] for all name field to get array request when you send form to server
example :

```
 '<input type="text" name="kp_produk[]" class="form-control">'+
```

and make button add like (jquery) example

```
<button onclick="$('form').append(blueprint)">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
var dom=$($('.saham')[0]).clone();
//copy dom
$('.form-horizontal').html(dom):
//paste dom
```

dont forget to add [] on name tag dom input to set data send to array, because if you not set. data with key kp_produk value is last tag name with name kp_produk

if you use [] (kp_product[]) data will set to array

```
kp_product=['anu1',anu2];
```